# Can't control floating button for KivyMD FIleManager

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to use the FileManager for KivyMD to select and execute a function using a certain path, but I can't assign a function to the floating checkmark button in the FileManager. I read something in the docs about the select_directory_on_press_button attribute, but it isn't working for me.

Here is my code:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.toast import toast

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def select_path(self, path, args):
        print("selected")
        self.file_manager.current_path = path

    def exit_manager(self, args):
        self.file_manager.close()

    def confirm(self):
        print("confirmed")
        self.file_manager.close()
        print(open(self.file_manager.current_path).read())

    def fileman(self, args):
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager = self.exit_manager,
            ext = [".txt"]
        )

        self.file_manager.select_dir_or_file = self.select_path

        self.file_manager.select_directory_on_press_button = self.confirm

        self.file_manager.show("C:/Users/hiami/Downloads/")

    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()

        screen.add_widget(MDFlatButton(
            text = "press me",
            pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            on_release = self.fileman
        ))

        return screen

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on a file or dir, the method `select_dir_or_file` is automatically called and current path is set. Thus you don't need these lines, <strike>`self.file_manager.select_dir_or_file = self.select_path`</strike> and

<strike>`self.file_manager.select_directory_on_press_button = self.confirm`</strike> (This will call `self.select_path` internally)

I added a toast message in the method `select_path`

```py
    def select_path(self, path, *args):
        toast(path)
        print("selected")
        #self.file_manager.current_path = path # This is automatically set.
```

Also all your 'args' are supposed to be varargs or '*args'.

Comment: thanks for the fixes, but I'm really looking for a way to assign the floating button a function. I know you can set it so that clicking on it does the same thing as clicking on the files, but I want to specifically have a function that runs when I click on the floating button.

Comment: May not be a good option, nonetheless did you try override the method `select_directory_on_press_button` ?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't do anything at all.

Comment: It should've worked. How did you try ?